# Android Studio: "Allocation Tracker Nothing to Show"

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-leaks

I am trying to Identify memory leaks with the Android Studio Allocation Tracker but when i follow the [description](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-allocation.html) I simply get a nice empty window saying  "nothing to show"

[image]

According to the description a nice representation of where all my memory has been allocated should be shown now.

Can someone please help me? I have spend two days now trying to come up with a good way to identify memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in my screenshot i had pending platform and plugin updates. I updated and now it works...